# nginx error location for all servers

Tags: nginx, error-handling, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

Is it possible to define a common location for all servers? From [nginx location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation I've seen that location depends on server. I would like to do something like this:

```
...
http {
    error_page  404                    /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 501 502 503 504    /error/50x.html;

    location ^~ /error/ {
        internal;
        root /var/www/nginx/errors;
    }

    server {
        ...
    }

    server {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I've tried setting:

```
http {
    ...
    root /var/www/nginx/errors; # also with root /var/www/nginx
    ...
}
```

with no success: always showing nginx default error page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a common location for all servers?

No.

You could make separate file and `include` it into all your servers.

/etc/nginx/error-location.inc:

```
location ^~ /error/ {
    internal;
    root /var/www/nginx/errors;
}
```

And then:

```
server {
    ...
    include error-location.inc;
}

server {
    ...
    include error-location.inc;
}
```